How to deal with chunk data for cronjob with BullMQ?
I am working on a cronjob with BullMQ node module.
I have 3000 users and I want to seperate 3 jobs, which one job is for 1000 users, and process cronjob.
But when I run this code, it performs many tasks.
const Queue = require('bullmq').Queue;
const Worker = require('bullmq').Worker;
const IORedis = require('ioredis');
const connection = new IORedis({maxRetriesPerRequest: null});
  
const myQueue = new Queue('MyQueue', {connection});

myQueue.add('job1', {page: 1}, {
  repeat: {
      pattern: '* * * * *'
    },
  });
myQueue.add('job2', {page: 2}, {
  repeat: {
      pattern: '* * * * *'
    },
  });
myQueue.add('job3', {page: 3}, {
  repeat: {
      pattern: '* * * * *'
    },
  });

const worker = new Worker('MyQueue', async job => {
  if (['job1', 'job2', 'job3'].includes(job.name)) {
    console.log(`Processing ${job.name}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Skipping ${job.name}`);
  }
}, {connection});

I only expect:
Processing job1
Job1 with id repeat:0f6579d200bf5a419aff3c8e27c6844f:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job2
Job2 with id repeat:31da86090fb08e946da917ae7d7803a3:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job3
Job3 with id repeat:2fcf2b3f5b4c75f261e1b18122de6218:1713224040000 has been completed

But the result is coming like this:
Processing job1
Job1 with id repeat:0f6579d200bf5a419aff3c8e27c6844f:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job2
Job2 with id repeat:31da86090fb08e946da917ae7d7803a3:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job3
Job3 with id repeat:2fcf2b3f5b4c75f261e1b18122de6218:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job2
Job2 with id repeat:43460e979617272ff738de6b1bc91ac5:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job3
Job3 with id repeat:6466183965f2fcfc37fb4a45eebf19ee:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job2
Job2 with id repeat:d453511562d3dcf31136cfc737433a85:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job3
Job3 with id repeat:ebe355420d8b30272e351063cc3073e2:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job2
Job2 with id repeat:63d53b94e1f84e3ad2b2507a3f59ecc0:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job3
Job3 with id repeat:a07aabec19f83a426707551ef36e9659:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job2
Job2 with id repeat:bf4162a60feabd3c853e15a853046382:1713224040000 has been completed
Processing job3
Job3 with id repeat:db44ec844a46f4f7209f129667c32f05:1713224040000 has been completed
...

So many jobs are working.
Is this cached jobs?

you have added pattern: '* * * * *' that's why your job is repeating in every second. remove it if you want to run once, or correct it with your requirment

Thanks for your opinion.
But I don't think so.
Because that means cronjob working on every minute, not on every second.

ohh okay i missed it thanks for correcting me.
please try check this failed and complete event and log results for debug myQueue.on('failed' ,(reason) => {} ) and myQueue.on('completed',(data) => {})

If you connect to Redis and run zrange bull:MyQueue:repeat 0 100, you should see the list of jobs that will repeat every minute for MyQueue. bullmq is smart enough to not duplicate cron entries when you run myQueue.add('job1'.. if the arguments are exactly the same, but it sounds like you have cached cron jobs that are also running when you add the worker.
I ran your code locally, and it does work the way that you'd want: it kicks off a worker that processes the jobs once per minute. Kicking off the worker multiple times doesn't create multiple repeatable jobs, so I think it's something about the data stored in your redis.
zrange bull:MyQueue:repeat 0 100
1) "job1::::* * * * *"
2) "job2::::* * * * *"
3) "job3::::* * * * *"

